# Regular Expression to replace AND

Tags: regex

I am trying to use a regular expression to replace the "AND" is this clause however I just want to replace the first "AND" that falls after the between statement with 'BLAH'.

Can someone please help me with this:

Sample string

```
AND UserId= 3 AND CreditScore BETWEEN 680 AND 720 AND UserId = 3 AND CreditScore between 800 and 900 and UserId= 3 and 1 = 1 and Income between 212319 and 212320 and 1= 1
```

Sample result

```
AND UserId= 3 AND CreditScore BETWEEN 680 BlAH 720 AND UserId = 3 AND CreditScore between 800 BlAH 900 and UserId= 3 and 1 = 1 and Income between 212319 BlAH 212320 and 1= 1
```

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression to do this? If you stop hard-coding values in your SQL and use parameters instead, you don't have to resort to this type of fix. (Your WHERE is all fouled up anyway; all of the `1=1` portions are going to louse up your results.)

Comment: What would be a cleaner way to replace the first and after a between statement other than a regular expression? As I stated above this is a SAMPLE string.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There's probably a better approach.

Comment: Why would you need to "replace the first AND`? Do you mean the `3` you're matching to `UserId`? Or the entire `UserId = 3` itself? Your question is really unclear. What do you want the statement to look like afterward?

Comment: I have updated the question with a sample result.

Comment: You should be specific. If you select an answer that doesn't reflect your problem statement, people will wonder if you are confused. `First AND after BETWEEN, with only numbers between.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on  case insensitive mode to do a case insensitive match.

```
(?i)(between\s+\d+\s+)AND(?=\s+\d+)
```

Replace the matched string with `$1BLAH`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qW8wQ6/12)